# Should I include node_modules when trying to create/publish azure devops extension tasks?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Based on Azure explanations I should:

> The agent doesn't automatically install the required modules because
> it's expecting your task folder to include the node modules. To
> mitigate this, copy the node_modules to buildandreleasetask. As your
> task gets bigger, it's easy to exceed the size limit (50MB) of a VSIX
> file. Before you copy the node folder, you may want to run npm install
> --production or npm prune --production, or you can write a script to build and pack everything.

But i am getting wired error when trying to publish package that include node_modules.

`error: A token is not valid. Refer to RFC 2616 for correct grammar of content types.`

This error is both from browser when I try to upload `vsix` file and from console when i try to `tfx extension publish`.

When node_modules are not present in `vsix` extension is updated/uploaded but it does not work since it is missing node_modules.

Btw, `vsix` is 15mb with node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm prune --production` shrank size of `vsix` file and extension is uploaded.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it's resolved, thanks.